# Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - timed out

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, terminal, cocoapods

I'm using a *Mac Mini with Big Sur (Version: 11.2.3 (20D91))* and when running this command: `sudo gem install cocoapods` 
I'm getting the following error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - timed out (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I don't know what to do, please help!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay I finally managed to solve it by following this steps:

1. **Disable IPv6**, here's how: [How to disable IPv6 in Mac OS X](https://support.blindsidenetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050168052-How-to-disable-IPV6)
2. **Restart Mac**
3. **Run** `sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org` in terminal without changing directories.

I hope I can help anyone facing the same issue, since I know it can be really frustrating and it takes time that could've been used by working in your projects.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 in Ubuntu did the trick for me as well. Thank you

Comment: Worked without restarting, and just running `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. But why?!?

Comment: Thanks! I fixed also my gem bundler problem with same configuration on my Mac 13 Venture

Comment: Disabling IPv6 helped for Mac Air M2 2022.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 in Mac M2 fixed the problem for me as well, thank you!
PS: I recommend not using sudo with gem install.

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading using homebrew

```
arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods
```

this is for arm based mac

```
brew install cocoapods
```

this is for intel mac

Comment: `brew install cocoapods` works also on ARM as at 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `darth_dever`'s answer, instead of step 3 run 
`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` in the terminal,
then `run arch -x86_64 pod install` in the ios folder
that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing this problem on a Linux guest machine (e.g an Ubuntu installed on VirtualBox, VMWare). Please Go to **Setting -> Network -> Attached to NAT** to solve the problem.
[image: Net work NAT]