I can't install rails, command gem install rails is not working for me
Im trying to install rails but every time I run the command gem install rails I get the following error:
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - IO::TimeoutError: Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org:443 (Blocking operation timed out!) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
Notes:

Im using Windows 11
I tried to run the command in git batch and windows cmd
Im not connected to a proxy
I have a decent connection to internet, I can access normally to https://rubygems.org/
Ruby version: ruby 3.3.5 (2024-09-03 revision ef084cc8f4) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
Node version: v20.18.0
Sqlite3 version: 3.46.1 2024-08-13 09:16:08 c9c2ab54ba1f5f46360f1b4f35d849cd3f080e6fc2b6c60e91b16c63f69a1e33 (64-bit)
Sorry for my english


Did you try to disable IP V6 on windows (here : https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/how-to-disable-tcpipv6-ipv6-on-windows-11 ) ? It seemed to work for someone on Mac that had the same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66936546/6270743
